# Initial commands before going in recursion

Tags: haskell

Maybe the title is a bit confusing so let me explain with an example:

Let's say i want to "print" lines of strings in a nice way. as input i would give a list with pair of ints and strings (in the case below: [(1,A),(2,B),(3,C)]). This would give the output:

```
|NUMBER|LETTER|
---------------
|1     |A     |
|2     |B     |
|3     |C     |
---------------
```

My try (where i use pseudocode functions printLine and printRow, which do what the name says):

```
prettyString :: [(Int,String)] -> [String]
prettyString [] = [printLine]
prettyString t@(top:rows) = printRow : prettyString rows
```

Now to finally get to my point: the code above goes in recursion and will give an output like

```
|1     |A     |
|2     |B     |
|3     |C     |
---------------
```

So it doesn't take the header with it (which makes sense, because i didn't do anything with it). But i'm stuck of thinking of a way how to manually add those lines at the top. So that, before going in recursion, i can do an "initial command" and already add those strings to the list.

Hope someone understands my problem .. thanks anyway !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You render the lines in a helper function, and you define an outer one that writes the header, so:

```
prettyString :: [(Int, string)] -> [String]
prettyString xs = "|NUMBER|LETTER|" : printLine : prettyString' xs

prettyString' :: [(Int,String)] -> [String]
prettyString' [] = [printLine]
prettyString' t@(top:rows) = printRow : prettyString' rows
```

Comment: Wow, that's simple. Thanks!

Comment: Can i perhaps ask you a follow up question? The pseudo function printLine, which is used in the base case needs a parameter. I want it to use the t variable (used in the recursive case). But i got an error for doing this. Do you know an easy work around? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The list of items is `xs`, so in the `prettyString`, you can use `printLine xs`.

Comment: so you mean that i would have .. : prettyString’ xs : printLine xs . Isn’t doing this possible in the prettyString’ function base case itself . (I know it gives the same result but just curious)

Comment: @Wouter: but in the `prettyString'` basecase, you only have an empty list left. If you need to work with the entire list, you will need to pass this in each recursive call, and thus not only the tail (then you thus recurse with two parameters).

Comment: Ah yes! That makes sense. Thnx

Comment: Sorry for the late comment but i get an error while doing the above. So we now have (rule 2 in your comment):
prettyString xs = "|NUMBER|LETTER|" : printLine xs : prettyString' xs
, and i want it to be
prettyString xs = "|NUMBER|LETTER|" : printLine xs : prettyString' xs : printLine xs
but this gives me an error, do you know why? (So i put the : printLine xs after having went in recursion).

Comment: !@Wouter: that's because3 `prettyString' xs` is a *list* of strings, so you should append this, like: `prettyString xs = "|NUMBER|LETTER|" : printLine xs : prettyString' xs ++ [printLine xs]`.

Answer (score 1):

Make another function that appends the header to the output of `prettyString`, like so:

```hs
prettyTable :: [(Int, String)] -> [String]
prettyTable t = ["|NUMBER|LETTER|", printLine] ++ prettyString t
```